# SCI on MC9S12 can't receive data

Tags: c

I have been stumped for a couple days.  I am simply trying to transmit and receive data using SCI1 on my dragon 12 board(MC9S12).  I have successfully transmit data to the PC however I can't seem to receive data.

The Rx led on my board never lights up.  I know data is being sent to the board successfully because I have a usb/serial cord the has a  little led that blinks when I send data to the board.

Here is my code:

```
void main(void)
{
     set24MHzClock();

     initializeLCD();

     clearDisplay();

     SCI1BDH=0x00;    //48MHz/2=24Mhz, 24Mhz/16= 1.5MHz, 1.5MHz/9600=156
     SCI1BDL=156;     //baud rate

     SCI1CR1 = 0x00;

     SCI1CR2 = 0x0C;

     for( ; ; )
     {
          if(SCI1SR1 & 0x20) //never receives data
          {
               clearDisplay();
               RXdata = SCI1DRL;       

               displayChar(RXdata);

               cl = SCI1SR1;

               displayCString("Rx");
          }

          SerWrite('0'); //this works
          wait500ms(); 
     }
}
```

I've tried multiple different things... everything from making this interrupt driven, separating into different functions, etc.  I've also changed the control registers to everything but still no Rx led showing up.

Comment: I don't know anything about this device, but I'd be (1) looking for working code samples of what you're trying to do (2) double checking the data sheet to ensure I haven't forgotten to flip an "enable Rx" bit somewhere, and (3) putting the Rx pin on the 'scope to see what bit patterns are coming across.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by using SCI0... exact same code - different port and result.